# My keys lag when typing

Tags: keyboard

My keys lag when typing. I have to press hard before the letter prints. It is slow. I have win 7 HP x64. I have an Emachine keyboard and desktop PC. Changing the  keyboard settings did not help. I need numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there are two options here:

1. It's a hardware issue. I lean towards this option because you said you have to press hard before the letter prints, suggesting some issue with the keyboard itself. If the keyboard is old, this is to be expected - most keyboards, as with mice, actually have a keypress rating, or about how many times you can press a given key and get a good result out of it before the keyboard starts the fail. Try using a different keyboard. If the same thing happens, we can probably eliminate the keyboard as the cause.
2. It's a software issue. This seems less likely to me, but I have seen this sort of thing happen (albeit rarely). Perhaps your computer is ridiculously bogged down by some process running in the background? I've seen computer slowed down by processes eating all their CPU power react excessively slow to keypresses. Check task manager for the CPU usage when the computer reacts slowly to keypresses. Also, try confirming that you actually have to press hard to get the keypress to register -- try just giving a key a firm, solid tap and see how long it takes to register. If it does register (and you didn't have to tap very hard), it's most likely an issue on your computer's end. If it doesn't register at all, that points to the aforementioned hardware issued. If your CPU isn't bogged down by anything, check the settings for key repeat delay (i.e. if you were hold down a key, what's the delay between registered keypresses?). Increase it and see if that helps.